# Getting error in migrating to swift 4

Tags: swift4

I am converting my code to swift 4 but xCode is giving me below error.[image]

what could be reason , current swift version is 3.2

Comment: how did you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the dialog, you need to successfully build your project first before migrating to swift 4

Comment: what if it is building correctly, but we get this issue?